# Can I run Java EE Programs on default JRE that oracle provides with java SE JDK?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-6

Recently I installed JDK toolkit downloaded by Oracle website.

I need to know how to run java EE programs on my computer. Should I install any other tools for run that program?

Comment: Well I suppose that you will need at least a Java EE container (JBoss, ...) or maybe simply a servlet container (Tomcat, Jetty, ...). They are required to run `.war` web application files.

Comment: You will need a Java EE compliant app server which provides a Java EE implementation.  Here is a listing of all app servers that are compliant: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/compatibility-jsp-136984.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run JavaEE applications, you must have a JavaEE **application server** running on your machine, from any of the available **JavaEE product providers**.

The JavaEE product provider is the company that designs and makes available for purchase the JavaEE platform APIs, and other features defined in the JavaEE specification.

Here's a summary of some of the available JavaEE implementations out there:
http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/the-great-java-application-server-debate-with-tomcat-jboss-glassfish-jetty-and-liberty-profile/